# HtmlWebpackPlugin - inject js in body at a specifc place

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin, asset-management

I am using HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject javascript into my template file:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        ...
        <?php echo $this->inlineScript(); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/vendor.js?a4212b4b10c2d4d2d73e"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I need the generated bundle to be injected before the PHP code `<?php echo $this->inlineScript(); ?>`, to let inline scripts work properly (they require JQuery, which will be loaded inside vendor.js).

Result should be:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/vendor.js?a4212b4b10c2d4d2d73e"></script>
        <?php echo $this->inlineScript(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe it is possible to use a placeholder like `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.??? %>` or something similar? If it does not work with HtmlWebpackPlugin, is there another webpack plugin I can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Put the following code where you want to include your js files:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js.length; i++) {%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[i] %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

and set `inject` in HtmlWebpackPlugin options to false.

Keep in mind that you need to inject other stuff (css, meta tags, etc.) by hand, too. F.e. CSS:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css.length; i++) {%>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[i] %>">
<% } %>
```

Comment: You can also use `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags` and `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.bodyTags`, see [example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/custom-insertion-position#custom-insertion-example)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I did the following:

(1) install the HtmlWebpackPlugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin)

```
npm i html-webpack-plugin
```

(2) update my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
// ...
plugins: [
    // ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'template.html',
        filename: 'file.html',
        inject: false,
        minify: false,
        templateParameters: (compilation, assets) => {
            const css = assets.css.map((filePath) => `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${filePath}" />`).join("\n");
            const js = assets.js.map((filePath) => `<script src="${filePath}"></script>`).join("\n");
            return { css, js };
        },
    }),
  
    }),
    // ...
],};
```

(3) add these tags within my template. This will tell webpack where to place the CSS and JS files.

```
 <!-- Webpack CSS -->
<%= css %>

<!-- Webpack JS -->
<%= js %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I am too late, but you can use [script-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin). This can set the script as `defer` which can defer the execution until the DOM is parsed. Additionally you can inject this script in `head` of html to start fetching it in parallel but executing at the end :

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'template.ejs', inject: 'head'}),
  new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({ defaultAttribute: 'defer' }),
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe also possible (didn't test).

Comment: Not related at all.